# How to avoid "Entities passed to the choice field must be managed. Maybe persist them in the entity manager?"

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

1. [Generated Entities](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html) from existing database
2. [Generated CRUD](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_doctrine_crud.html) controller

But it does not work with exception message:

> Entities passed to the choice field must be managed. Maybe persist them in the entity manager?

**Entity**

```
/**
 * Question
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="question", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="question_category_id", columns={"question_category_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Question
{
    //...

    /**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\QuestionCategory
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\QuestionCategory")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="question_category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $questionCategory;

    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->questionCategory = new QuestionCategory();
    }

    //...
}
```

**Form**

```
class QuestionType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('questionCategory');
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Question'
        ));
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
class QuestionController extends Controller
{
   //...

   /**
     * Creates a new Question entity.
     * @Route("/new", name="question_new")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {
        $question = new Question();
        $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\QuestionType', $question);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($question);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('question_show', array('id' => $question->getId()));
        }

        return $this->render('question/new.html.twig', array(
            'question' => $question,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }

//...
}
```

Deep debugging gives nothing to me. How to fix it?

Test repository to reproduce error: https://github.com/sectus/question.test.local

Comment: Are you doing any initialization in `Question` entity class?

Comment: @OscarPérez, yes, just creating QuestionCategory Entity

Comment: Then this is the problem. You are setting a `QuestionCategory` that is not managed. Could you please add the constructor's code?

Comment: @OscarPérez , I've created test repository which you could explore: https://github.com/sectus/question.test.local

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the code shown on your GitHub project, the `Question` entity has the following constructor:

```
public function __construct() 
{
    $this->questionCategory = new QuestionCategory();
}
```

When you create an `entity` form field, it can only contain values that are managed by doctrine, but your new  `questionCategory` is not managed.

Usually, the best solution is just to not fill this entity field in the constructor, but only in those places you strictly need it. When building a form, Synfony will fill it for you after submitting and calling `$form->handleRequest()`.

So, in your case, just remove the `Question` entity's constructor.

After that, you'll also need to implement the `__toString()` method in `QuestionCategory` entity:

```
 public function __toString(){
       return 'whatever you neet to see the type`;
 }
```

Comment: Without it I have other error "Object of class AppBundle\Entity\QuestionCategory could not be converted to string"

Comment: Thank you very much. It's so obvious... it's like eclipse of my mind.

Comment: @sectus , what do you mean?

Comment: I had error about object to string conversion (X problem). I've created construcor and got other error (Y problem). Instead of solving X with another approach I tried and tried to solve Y.

Comment: Ahh, I see, with XY I thought it was something aboug DNA... :-D

Answer (score 11):

Beware, this error can also be raised when using `'by_reference' => false,` in your form type with relations that are not `ManyToMany`.
An unfortunate copy/paste put me in this situation.

Answer (score 5):

In my case I was having this issue because I was using `EntityType` instead of `ChoiceType`, to build the selectList.

`EntityType` display only data from database, instead `ChoiceType` can display "not managed" objects.

I hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. 
In my case, I was caching my entity in order to pre-populate  an `EntityType` field. 
Now I'm caching the identifier and getting the entity in my `data` field option with an `EntityRepository::find()`.

Answer (score 3):

This error means the attribute `questionCategory` which is a relationship, *is not managed* by the **EntityManager**. For this to be done automatically, add a **cascade-persist** in your Doctrine Mapping for `questionCategory` attribute:

**Entity**

```
/**
 * Question
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="question")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Question
{
    //...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(
     *       targetEntity="QualityBundle\Entity\QuestionCategory", 
     *       cascade={"persist"}
     * )
     */
    private $questionCategory;

    //...
}
```

This way, when you call `$em->persist($question);`, the `QuestionCategory` linked to your `Question` will automatically be persisted as well.

Comment: Nothing has changed width persist :^ ( Replaced persist with null, and i've got form with textbox instead of select. Also, I do not want to change records from QuestionCategory.

Answer (score 3):

There are different reasons that create this issue.

In my case, I fixed it changing

> by_reference' => false

to

> by_reference' => true

in the CRUD controller.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it just was because by my fault I was using the `QueryManager` instead of `EntityManager` to find the entity in my controller.